# Display random number and sorting

Tags: c#, sorting, if-statement, random

I am hitting a wall here, my fellow people. Is there a way where I can generate random numbers, and then indicate them if they are positive or negative?

I tried using an `if` statement, but as you know once it hits the `if` it doesn't go to the `else`.

Please keep your code simple in such a way that any person would understand what's going on or at least indicate what's going on in your code.

How can I fix this mistake?

```
Random rnd = new Random();

Console.WriteLine("\n5 random integers from -100 to 100:");
for (int X = 1; X <= 5; X++)
{
    if (X >= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("These are the positive numbers: {0}", rnd.Next(0, 100));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("These are the negative numbers: {0}", rnd.Next(-100, 0));
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You are looping through X values from 1 to 5. All of them are positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code... Don't compare X; you have to compare the random number.

```
Random rnd = new Random();

Console.WriteLine("\n5 random integers from -100 to 100:");
for (int X = 1; X <= 5; X++)
{
    int y = rnd.Next(-100, 100);
    if (y >= 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("These are the positive numbers: {0}", y.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("These are the negative numbers: {0}", y.ToString());
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: @TheBoringGuy mark it as an answer if it has solved your problem

Comment: yup this did answer my question but there is a timer :B

Comment: @TheBoringGuy This will print out "These are the positive numbers" and "These are all the negative numbers" multiple times. Why would you want the redundancy? Just display all the positive numbers and then all of the negative numbers like in the answer I provided.

Comment: @JasonRoell I know it does but its more dense so its easier for me to remember I have been messing around with C# for only a month, I am not ready yet for the big picture I wanna slowly ease myself into it :) but I am still thankful.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the value of `x`. It will always remain positive. Try this in your loop:

```
int i = rnd.Next(-100, 100);

if (i >= 0)
    //It is positive
else
    //It is negative
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the work:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int randomNumber = rnd.Next(-100, 100);

if (randomNumber >= 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Positive (with Zero)");
else 
    Console.WriteLine("Negative");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do exactly what you are looking for:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var rnd = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("\n5 random integers from -100 to 100:");
        List<int> random = new List<int>();

        for (int X = 1; X <= 5; X++)
        {
            random.Add(rnd.Next(-100, 100));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("These are the positive numbers:");
        foreach (int number in random)
        {
            if (number >= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(number);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("These are the negative numbers:");
        foreach (int number in random)
        {
            if (number < 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(number);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This will print out 5 numbers and have them in a result set displayed like below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you kindly sir, but I already found my answer but im still gonna check this out. thanks :)

Comment: @JasonRoell this is not right way to ask OP to mark answer, also OP ask for simplest way to do that and using collections for such problem is not simple, it is performance overhead

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rnd = new Random();

Console.WriteLine("\n5 random integers from -100 to 100:");
for (int X = 1; X <= 5; X++)
{
    int Y = rnd.Next(-100, 100);

    if (Y > 0)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("These are the positive numbers: {0}", Y);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("These are the negative numbers: {0}", Y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `continue` is another way around:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
Console.WriteLine("\n5 random integers from -100 to 100:");
for (int X = 1; X <= 5; X++)
{
    int y = rnd.Next(-100, 100);
    if (y < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("These are the negative  numbers: {0}", y);
        continue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("These are the positive numbers: {0}", y);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```